# Attach picture to action using facebook open graph stories v4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using facebook SDK 4. and the open graph stories api. I am able to create an action and share it when there is no user created image, but when adding an image, I can't figure out how to link the SharePhotoContent to the action created.

My code is:

```
ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder actionBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder();

    actionBuilder.setActionType("fbclimbmystats:on_sight"); //name space needed
actionBuilder.putObject("route", fbRoute); 
ShareOpenGraphAction action = actionBuilder.build();

//Create a Bitmap image to add
Bitmap bitmap = null;
if (photoPath !=  null){
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
}

SharePhoto photo = null;
if (bitmap != null){
    photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(bitmap)
    .setUserGenerated(true)
    .build();
}

ShareContent content;

if (photo!=null){
    content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
    .addPhoto(photo)
    .build();
}
else {
    ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder contentBuilder = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder();
    contentBuilder.setPreviewPropertyName("route"); // No namespace here
    contentBuilder.setAction(action);
    content =  contentBuilder.build();
}
```

So if the user has taken a photo, I want to share it in the story. And to do that, I create a SharePhotoContent. But then it is not linked to the action and the dialog displayed is basically just sharing the photo, which is not the point.

The documentation from facebook states:

> To attach pictures of a book to the books.reads action, an app should load images as a Bitmap and pass those to the Share dialog when it's opened.
>
> The Share dialog shows a preview of the story and use Bitmap passed above in the story preview instead of using the object's image.

So what am I missing? Should I first initiate the dialog with the ShareOpenGraphContent and then pass the SharePhotoContent ? if yes how?

Also still regarding the sharing of user generated photos using open graph, do I need to have the Story reviewed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is incorrect. Here is an example of attaching an image to an OG share dialog invocation.

```
private void invokeOGShareDialog(Bitmap bitmap) {

    // Create OG object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
            .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, " +
                    "sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
            .build();

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads")
            .putObject("book", object)
            .putPhoto("image", photo)
            .build();

    // Create the content
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(this, content);

}
```

Comment: Ok it definitely works, but now the image does not appear as user generated. It appears as a small pic next to the graph story. Any idea why it does that?